# Why passing a member of an object to a function and changing it doesn't change the member in parent object?

Tags: javascript

Why when I pass `childObject` directly and change it, `object.childObject` stays the same. While passing object and changing `object.childObject` does change `object.childObject` outside the function.

In my head I always pass by reference, so if I change the value of what `childObject` points to in `f_b()`, shouldn't it also change it in `object.childObject?`

If I pass child object:

```
f_b(someObject) {
  someObject = {
    b: 2
  }

  console.log("childObject inside f_b is ", someObject)
}

f_a() {
  let object = {
    childObject: {
      a: 1
    }
  }

  this.f_b(object.childObject);

  console.log("childObject inside f_a is ", object.childObject)
}

f(a)
```

Running F(a) would output:

```
childObject inside f_b is {b: 2}
childObject inside f_a is {a:1}
```

If I pass parent object:

```
f_b(someObject) {
  someObject.childObject = {
    b: 2
  }
  
  console.log("childObject inside f_b is ", someObject)
}
f_a() {
  let object = {
    childObject: {
      a: 1
    }
  }

  this.f_b(object);

  console.log("childObject inside f_a is ", object.childObject)
}
```

Running F(a) would output:

```
childObject inside f_b is {b: 2}
childObject inside f_a is {b: 2}
```

Why doesn't the former output the same as the latter?

Comment: You... You aren't changing the object. You're basically doing `let a = 1; a = 2;` and asking "why is 1 not being changed into 2?"

Comment: "*In my head I always pass by reference*" - no. [JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1048572).  The `someObject` parameter always is a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `object.childObject` into the function (in the first sample), you pass a reference to the `childObject` value. In the function, you reassign the parameter to a *new* object, which is fine, but it will have no effect on the value of `object.childObject` because JavaScript is exclusively pass-by-value. The *value* of `object.childObject` is a reference to an object, and the function cannot change that.

The second piece of code explicitly updates the `childObject` property of the parent object, so that does what you expect. Because object values are references to an object, your function can change the "insides" of the passed-in object reference (so long as it isn't frozen and the property is writable).

In general, code like this:

```
function x(a) {
  a = 17;
}

var something = 1;
x(something);
```

can **never** change `something`.  Your case can be simplified to this:

```
function x(a) {
  a = 17;
}

var something = { property: 1 };
x(something.property);
```

Similarly, the value of `something.property` cannot be changed by the reassignment inside the function `x()`.